# Ubuntu One Sync specific folders to a special machine

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have around 4GB of data on my ubuntu one storage.

Today I've installed ubuntu one on a terminal system of my college. The Problem is, that the size of my home directory is limited to 500MB. So, if i start ubuntu one on that machine, my home directory is always full.

Is there a way, to tell the ubuntu-one client on that machine, only to sync a specific folder instead of pulling all available folders in the ubuntu-one-clound.

regards,
Simon

Answer (score 2):

I think it will sync everything that is in the Ubuntu One folder as default but the other folders you have added from your home folder (E.G. Photo's, Music etc) have to be subscribed to. So you could put only what you want on that machine in the "Ubuntu One" folder and keep everything else in another folder in home that has to be subscribed to!

Haven't tried it but it is a thought,

.: Cezz :.

Comment: Indeed that is a solution. Move all the non-essential files outside of ~/Ubuntu One and sync only the folders you want.

Comment: i think you've missunderstood my question a bit. I want to say the ubuntu-one client on the college-machine. "Fetch only this specific folder, and leave the other 4GB on the clound without downloading it" All other machines should be untouched of this.

Comment: I didn't understand, but I don't think what you want to do is possible because EVERYTHING in the Ubuntu one folder is synced to every machine...

The only possible way I can see to do it is to move everything out of the Ubuntu One folder and put them in different folders within your home Dir on one PC... you can then set those folders to Sync to Ubuntu One, and you then have the option on each machine of which Folders you want to **Subscribe** to!

Comment: okay, and how do I specify which folder should be fetched on a specific machine? Can not find something like this on the ubuntu client GUI. There is the option "stop syncronising this folder in nautilus", but this mean, the folder stops syncrhonising on all other devices too. It is not more in the ubuntu clound